# extract double quoted items in a phrase

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I would like to extract all double quoted phrase inside an input phrase and keep non matching elements as words

let's say i have "sales people" IT i want the output to be:

```
sales people

  IT
```

same thing for input="SO \"sales manager\" marketing \"management\""

the output is:

```
SO
sales manager
marketing
management
```

if input ="SO \"sales manager\" marketing management\" insurance"

the output is:

```
SO
sales manager
marketing
management
insurance
```

I have found the regex :but i don't know how to extract:

```
string InputText="SO \"sales manager\" marketing \"management\"" ;
string pattern0 = "^\"(.*?)\"$";
string pattern = "^(.*?)\"(.*?)\"(.*?)$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string[] temOperands;
bool isMatch = regex.IsMatch(InputText);
if (isMatch)
{
    //here goes the extraction
}
```

Comment: the question is simple delemit by double quotes.extract double quoted elements and the rest is extracted as simple words.

Comment: question changed.Please consider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need something like `"(?<word>[^"]+)"|(?<word>\w+)`. This will match both text in double quotes and single words:

```
var str = @"SO ""sales manager"" marketing hello ""management""";
var regex = new Regex(@"""(?<word>[^""]+)""|(?<word>\w+)");
var words = regex.Matches(str)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["word"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

For the test string this will return:

```
SO
sales manager
marketing
hello
management
```

Comment: this answer has nailed it.Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

The input string has only two words within double quotes "Sales manager" and "marketing". Below code can extract strings within double quotes.

```
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

        int x1 ;
        int nextPos=0;
        x1 = InputText.IndexOf('\"', 0) +1 ;
        while (x1 != -1)
        {
            if (x1 >= 0)
            { 
                nextPos = InputText.IndexOf('\"',x1);
                arr.Add(InputText.Substring(x1, nextPos - x1));
            }
            nextPos++;
            x1 = InputText.IndexOf('\"', nextPos) + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'replace'

```
string InputText="SO \"sales manager\" marketing \"management\"" ;
InputText=InputText.Replace("\"","\n");
```

in output you will have what you want.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use split function

```
string s="SO \"sales manager\" marketing \"management\"";
string[] ExtractedString= Regex.Split(s, "\"");
```

Comment: Shoaib,it doesn't take on consideration double quote at the start of the item and the end try "SO \"sales manager\" marketing management\"";;this should output sales manager <br>marketing <br>management